# Storing primitive vs reference types Javascript && example

Tags: javascript, variables, copy, javascript-objects, primitive-types

I have a very hard time with this topic.

For example at this code:

```
let test = "primitive";
const arr = [test];
console.log(arr);

test = "changedPrimitive";
console.log(test, arr);
```

I can't understand why the test variables value changed but the object(array) remained with the old string

Can someone explain me how this 2 types are **stored** analytically(memory heap, stack, memory address,value..) and how they behave when we are **creating copies**(from one variable to another).

For example

```
    let newyear = 2000;
    let year = newyear;
    newyear = 2022;
    console.log(year, newyear);
```

When copying a primitive value from what i understood reading some articles is that:   **newyear** variable points to a new **memory address** in the stack which holds the value **2000** and when we create **year** variable it points to the **same address** that why the both hold the value 2000, finally when we change the **newyear** to **2022** a new address is created with that value.
While from others i read that the 2 variables have nothing to do with each other, so year does not point to the address of newyear.. They value is just copied from one variable to another..

Comment: Javascript runs *order of operations* linearly -> top down, so `test` is set, then `arr` is defined using `test` value, you console log the `arr`, it gives you the value it was set as in the ***order*** it was set. You then redefine `test`, but you never update the arrays value directly, so it will still give you the value that `test` was when the array was defined. Your second example is similar, you define newyear, then set year to newyear, then you change the value of newyear. Order of operations dictates the arrays value to be the value of newyear that was set prior to defining `year`.

Comment: The array and variable both contain references to the primitive string. When you change one reference, it doesn't affect the other reference.

Comment: Whether the two references to 2000 are in the same memory location is an implementation detail, which may vary between implementations. You need to think about these things more abstractly.

Comment: It could even vary depending on the number -- it's not uncommon to use immediate data for small numbers, and pointers for large numbers.